# IIS 7.5 Request Filtering - best practice rules?

Tags: iis-7.5, best-practices, request-filtering

Im looking for a set of best practice rules for Request Filtering similar to what UrlScan adds by default.

Any suggestions or an example list of filters is much appreciated. By default IIS 7.5 only has File Name Extensions, and Hidden Segments filters.

Thanks in advance,
Vindberg